# Chain select queries within an eager load?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I chain 2 or more select tags within an eager load?
I am using select because I only want to load these 2 columns, nothing else. Tried many things.

```php
    $teams = Team::with(['captain' => function($q) {
        $q->select('id', 'name')->where('show_name', true);
        $q->select('id', 'username')->where('show_username', true);
    }])
```

Obviously this first implementation will not work, but it shows what I am trying to achieve:

```php
        $q->select('id', 'name', 'username')
          ->where('show_name', true)
          ->orWhere('show_username', true);
    }])
```

This second implementation returns both `name` and `username` if either `show_name` or `show_username` is `true`. I wan't something like:

```php
        $q->select('id', 'name')
          ->where('show_name', true)
          ->orWhere() // ??
          ->select('id', 'username')
          ->where('show_username', true);
    }])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The SQL query result needs to be a table so you must have the same columns for each row. You can however conditionally have the real username or name value in the column as below:

```
 $teams = Team::with(['captain' => function($q) {
    $q->select('id', 
         \DB::raw('IF(show_username, username, NULL) as username'),  
         \DB::raw('IF(show_name, name, NULL) as name')
    );
}])
```